# How to get Configuration from WebApplicationFactory?

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I am currently writing an integration test to test my APIs using WebApplicationFactory.

I have created a CustomWebApplicationFactory. I want to read the default appsettings.json that is found in the main web project. I know this can be achieved as below:

```
private static readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration; // Global

// Inside Constructor
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)

 _configuration = builder.Build();

// To get connectionstring

var connStr = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
```

In my case, I want to use appsettings.json by default. Is there a way I can retrieve the connectionstring by reading appsettings.json from
main Web project without defining the AddJsonFile codes in the constructor?

Answer (score 6):

Since I inject the `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` into my integration test classes, I use the following:

```
public class MyIntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
{
  private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _app;
  private readonly IConfiguration? _config;
  
  public MyIntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> app) 
  {
    _app = app;
    _config = app.Services.GetService<IConfiguration>();
  }

}
```

Comment: this worked for me, should be the answer

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way (code below). I.e. intercept the builder and build the config the same way the service does.

```
public class MyApiServiceWrapper : WebApplicationFactory<Api.Startup>
{
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
        {
            // expand default config with settings designed for Integration Tests
            conf.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "appsettings.Integration.json"));
            conf.AddEnvironmentVariables();

            // here we can "compile" the settings. Api.Setup will do the same, it doesn't matter.
            _configuration = conf.Build();
        });

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(srv =>
        {
            // here you can change some internal services of the Api.Startup
            // and change them to mocks
        });

        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }

    public TConfig GetConfiguration<TConfig>()
    {
        // start my service to get the config built...
        this.CreateClient(); 
        // ... and then cast it to my type
        return _configuratio.Get<TConfig>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the following setup:

```
public class Fixtures
{
    public readonly WebApplicationFactory<WebApplication1.Program> Factory { get; }
    
    public Fixtures()
    {
        Factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Startup>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.Configure<YourSettings>(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Setting1 = "OverrideSetting1"
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If you use [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0), you could try requesting your settings from IServiceProvider using the [GetService<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) method:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly YourSettings _settings;
    
    public Test(Fixtures fixtures)
    {
        var settingsOptions = fixtures.Factory.Services.GetService<IOptions<YourSettings>>();
        _settings = settingsOptions?.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask for getting **default** settings (appsettings.json) and **without**  defining the AddJsonFile codes in the constructor.

### How it works

1. WebApplicationFactory by default use Environments.Development.
2. Then Configuration use appsettings.[environment].json

### Solution

If you want to change this approach, you have two choices:

#### Remove or rename the configutation file

Remove or rename the configutation file *appsettings.Development.json*. Because by default this configuration is add as optional. The application will now looking for *appsettings.json*.
On image you can see only two appsettings without appsettings.Development.json.

[image]

#### Change the environment

Change the environment to some new name, for example "Integration". Now it will looking for *appsettings.Integration.json*. If you don't have such file, it will use the default configuration file *appsettings.json*.

1. If you need the configuration *before* you call BuildServiceProvider(), the code look like this:

```
private IConfiguration _config;
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    // 1 - Set environment
    builder.UseEnvironment("Integration");

    // 2 - Get configuration from DI Container
    builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, conf) =>
    {
        _config = conf.Build();
    });


    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        // 3 - Use configuration (before BuildServiceProvider)
        var conn = this._config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                
        // some manipulation with services in DI container
        // ...
    });
}
```

2. If you can get the configuration *after* you call BuildServiceProvider(), the code can look like this:

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    // 1 - Set environment
    builder.UseEnvironment("Integration");

    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        // 2 - Get configuration from DI Container
        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var config = scopedServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();

        // 3 - Use configuration
        var connection = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    });
}
```

Personally, I prefer the last approach, because now I can simple add *appsettings.Integration.json* file and store some variables there. My application will look at it and get values.

[image]